# Terminate Program (CTRL+C) in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to execute one of the shell script that takes two parameters

1. Start of the Progress : start_process
2. Terminate the program: CTRL+C

The problem is when i call the shells script, it doesn't terminate the program so i manually CTRL+C to terminate the program

I've tried to apply couple of fixes but none of them working

**shell script**

```
 printf "start_process\n'\x03\'n" | pptslm  > logFile.txt
```

I managed to pass parameter "start_process" successfully but I am not able to pass "Ctrl+C or \x03" as parameter in shell script.

[image]

Comment: please 1) format your code properly 2) format your text properly and write in proper english

Comment: 1) The code you show does not use any parameters.  2)  From what you show, it is `pptslm` that need to be interrupted, did you try running it in background then sending the signal with `kill %1 SIGINT`?

Comment: You can see there are two parameter passing in Printf 1 ) "startProcess and 2)x03 (Which is equivalent to the CTRL+C). Originally, this utility asks me whether i want to start this process? if say yes startProcess then it start of the process. Once the process started, it asks me again where i want to continue with it so i press Ctrl+C to terminate it. So, i want to automate the same things in shell script. First input parameter(startProcess ) is submitted properly but somehow CTRL+C / interrupt thing doesn't pass from the shell script properly.

Comment: Can you put the job in the background; find the pid for the `printf` and then `kill -s SIGINT <pid>`?

Comment: @user1030128 You are not passing parameters to your script.  You are writing data on the script's stdin, which is different than passing a parameter.  And writing '\x03' on stdin is certainly not the same as sending a SIGINT.

Comment: You mean
./my-script.sh &
# Get its PID
PID=$!
# Wait for 2 seconds
sleep 2
# Kill it
kill -s SIGINT $PID

it gives me error like kill: SIGINT: invalid signal specification

Answer (score 3):

You don't "pipe" CTRL-C to a program, you send a *signal* to the process (BTW: pressing `CTRL-C` in a terminal is converted to a SIGINT signal). The standard tool for doing this is the `kill` command.

As you haven't provided the source for `myscript.sh` I'm taking a guess here:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# create child process
pptslm  >logFile.txt &
_pid=$!
echo "child PID ${_pid}"

# wait for 2 seconds
sleep 2

# kill child process using SIGINT
echo "Killing child PID ${_pid}"
kill -INT ${_pid}
exit 0
```

Comment: @user1030128 I don't understand your comment. If you want to wait until it completes, then why do you want to use `&` at all? If you use `&` and bash `wait ${_pid}` then there won't be anything left to kill.